# When finding the upper bound, why is a ceiling evaluated to a +1?

Tags: information-theory, upper-lower-bounds, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Why does removing the ceiling result in $a + 1$?

I'm reading Introduction to Data Compression by Guy E. Blelloch on page $19$ on Information Theory, here he is proving an upper bound.

$$
\begin{align}
1+\lceil-\log s\rceil &= 1+\lceil-\log_2(\prod_{i=1}^np_i)\rceil\\
&=1+\lceil\sum_{i=1}^n-\log_2p_i\rceil\\
&=1+\lceil\sum_{i=1}^ns_i\rceil\\
&\lt2+\sum_{i=1}^ns_i\\
\end{align}
$$

Where $s_i=\log_2\frac{1}{p_i}$. The ceiling was removed and $a + 1$ was added.

Comment: Do you agree that $\lceil x\rceil < x+1$ for all $x$?

Comment: Okay, yeah I agree.

Comment: Then set $x=\sum s_i$ and add $1$ to both sides of that inequality.

Comment: $\lceil\sum s_i\rceil+1<\sum s_i + 2$

Comment: Which is exactly that last step you were asking about.

Comment: if you could humor me, why not .000001?

Comment: I don't get what your point is. Do you not agree that the reasoning I've presented is valid? Which point of it do you not think is valid? (Just because you could perhaps imagine a _different_ reasoning that would _also_ be valid doesn't mean that this one isn't. Though in fact I cannot see at all which relevant reasoning here would involve the number $0.000001$).

Comment: Note also that it is _not_ true that, for example, $\lceil 3.141529\rceil < 3.141529+0.000001$.

Comment: The thing is the + 1 later on implies a large impact on the compression and I was wondering if x+1 is greater then ceil(x), surely an even smaller number like x+.01 is still greater than ceil(x). It seems to me, adding one is arbitrary

Comment: Hmm, I see.....

Comment: Okay, cool I get it.

Comment: What the hell is "$a$"?